# protractor-fail-fast plugin seems to be in conflict with grep options, separately both works fine

Tags: node.js, grep, jasmine, protractor

i've spotted the following problem when using both fail-fast plugin and grep functionality in protractor through protractor.conf file:

```
const failFast = require('protractor-fail-fast');
```

...

```
const config = {
  SELENIUM_PROMISE_MANAGER: false,
  chromeOnly: true,
  directConnect: true,
  disableChecks: true,
  capabilities: {
    browserName: 'chrome',
    chromeOptions: {
      args: ['--disable-remote-fonts', '--start-maximized'],
    },
  },
  chromeDriver: './../selenium/chromedriver.exe',
  baseUrl: '',
  allScriptsTimeout: timeout,
  getPageTimeout: timeout,
  framework: 'jasmine2',
  noGlobals: false,
  isExecutedInCI: false,
  failFastEnabled: false,
  plugins: [failFast.init()],
  specs: [],
  suites: null,
  jasmineNodeOpts: {
    stopSpecOnExpectationFailure: true,
    realtimeFailure: true,
    isVerbose: true,
    showColors: true,
    includeStackTrace: true,
    defaultTimeoutInterval: timeout,
    grep: '@tag',
},
```

onPrepare etc

Apparently when running them separately with grep=@tag or failFast ON(initialized) all is fine. Unfortunately when both used at the same time grep doesn't seem to be working anymore.
Did anyone has similar problem or maybe found a workaround. All suggestions more than welcome:)